# Rendering 'new' leads to a different url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When handling validation errors in a User form on my rails project, I have the instruction `render 'new'` if the user is not valid.

However, when this occurs, the url in the search bar changes.

Originally, it's `https://localhost:3000/signup` but when the user submit the forms and the `render 'new'` occurs, the URL becomes `https://localhost:3000/users`

Why is that?

Here's my `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Resources
  resources  :users, only: [ :new, :create ]

  # Application root
  root 'static_pages#home'

  # Static pages
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  # Users
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
post '/signup', to: 'users#new'
```

Comment: While this does solve the immediate issue it brings a bunch of history related issues that the rails conventions are designed to avoid. Learn the rules before you break them.

Answer (score 2):

In the Rails REST conventions you use different URI's to display the form to create a resource and for the forms `action` attribute which you POST to.

Lets say you have:

```
resources :pets
```

This gives us:

```
GET  /pets/new  => pets#new
POST /pets      => pets#create
```

We then have a typical form:

```
# posts to /pets
<%= form_for(@pet) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And a run of the mill controller:

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @pet = Pet.new
  end

  def create
    @pet = Pet.new(pet_params)
    if @pet.save
      redirect_to @pet
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

So when the user visits `/pets/new` and fills in the form the browser url should read `/pets` if the form is invalid. This is the intended behavior - posting to a different URL avoids a myriad of cache and history related issues.

From a restful standpoint its also correct - you're no longer viewing the new action - you're viewing the results of attempting to create a resource. The former is idempotent - the latter is not.

You need to recognize that the line `render :new` is short for `render template: 'pets/new'`. It does not redirect and it does not call the `new` action in the controller. It simply renders the template and returns it as the response to the current request.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of the way Rails handles routes. Most likely, the form on your signup page has something like:

```
<?= form_for @user do |f| ?>
```

If you look at the generated HTML you'll notice that the form is POSTing to the url `'/users'`. So when the signup form is submitted, the app is going to redirect you to `/users`.

This is the normal behavior in Rails. (see [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions))

If you want the URL to look like `/signup` you can add a named route for it:

```
# Users
get '/signup', to: 'lead_magnets#new'
post '/signup', to: 'lead_magnets#create'
```

Then in your signup form you'll need to explicitly reference the new signup path:

```
<?= form_for @user, url: signup_path do |f| ?>
```

The generated HTML should look like

```
<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/signup" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include recognize path?

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because when you submit your form, you're submitting it to some action from your `new` view. The action that the form submits to has a path, and you can see what the path is by typing:

```
rake routes
```

in your console and searching for the create action. When your validation fails in the create action, you call `render 'new'`.

**When you render a template, the url of the page being rendered will be the url / path of the controller action that rendered the template.**

In your case, whatever action you have that calls `render 'new'` will be the one determing the url once your template is rendered.